# Circular saw blade position: corded vs battery

Tags: tools, powertools, circular-saw

From admittedly fairly limited research I noticed that all corded circular saws have blade on the right of the handle, whereas battery operated ones have the blade on the left. What is the reasoning behind that?

Ok, so in light of the comments: somehow, all the saws I came by so far follow this pattern, this is why I asked. Let me ask this then: why are blades on different sides then?

I guess the last edit makes this question a duplicate of this: [Why does a cordless circular saw have the blade on the left?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/100448/why-does-a-cordless-circular-saw-have-the-blade-on-the-left/185254#185254)

Comment: All corded circular saws do not have blades on the right. There are left handed and right handed circular saws both corded and cordless.

Comment: Please expand your research! A much better question would be to ask _why_ some circular saws have the blade on the left and others on the right. (The answer isn't just for left/right handed people!)

Comment: You are incorrect - virtually all worm-drive framing saws (with cords) have the blade on the left.